# Error loading EPPlus 4.0.0.1 but the nuget reference is there.

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I am not 100% sure if this is a NuGet issue or a configuration issue elsewhere. I am trying to modify some code in a project that references EPPlus 3.x.x, all the projects in the entire solution do actually however in one of the projects (the one containing our entities) a colleague upgraded it to use 4.0.0.1 (which is the beta version). Here are the actual lines from the csproj files.

```
//from the project where our entities our housed
C:\work\Dev\SourceCode\Compass.Data\packages.config(7):  <package id="EPPlus" version="4.0.0-beta2" targetFramework="net40" />
//from the project I am trying to debug (step through).
C:\work\Dev\SourceCode\Compass.Business\packages.config(7):  <package id="EPPlus" version="3.1.3.3" targetFramework="net45" />
```

what is happening is that I keep getting the following error.

```
 System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'EPPlus, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ea159fdaa78159a1' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

looking in the packages folder I am seeing the following.

```
C:\work\Packages\EPPlus.4.0.0-beta2\lib\net20
```

I think the issue is that there is a net20 folder and the configuration says targetFramework="net40" but I not even sure of that. If that is the problem I don't know how to fix it either.

Hopefully someone can explain what is going on.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So - while I don't really have an answer as to why I do have an answer to this problem that may help someone trying to debug in the future.

after some testing I realized that this worked perfectly fine when you didn't have a debugger attached. The only time I had a problem was when I wanted to step through the code. To solve this I installed the version is was looking for into the GAC. I am not 100% sure why this worked but it did solve the problem for me.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd C:\work\Packages\EPPlus.4.0.0-beta2\lib\net20

C:\work\Packages\EPPlus.4.0.0-beta2\lib\net20>gacutil /i EPPlus.dll
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.33440
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Assembly successfully added to the cache

C:\work\Packages\EPPlus.4.0.0-beta2\lib\net20>gacutil /l epplus
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.33440
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies:
  epplus, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ea159fdaa78159a1, processorArchitecture=MSIL

Number of items = 1

C:\work\Packages\EPPlus.4.0.0-beta2\lib\net20>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it happened on a ASP.NET website.
I did update the EPPLus.dll reference, but the publish function has not replaced the old file with the new one.
Removed the dll manually and publishing again